# Internet connection drops for a few seconds

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, vpn, openvpn

I am having a problem with an internet connection, let me explain:

I use my phone to connect to a WiFi network that uses EAP-SIM. In fact, every person who has a SIM card from the "Free" carrier can connect to these kind of WiFi Hotspots.

These hotspots are hosted from people's routers in their home so I don't really have access to the router configuration.

Then, I use a USB cable to tether connection to my PC running **Windows 10**. The problem is that when I watch Youtube videos or download things on the internet, the connection **drops for some seconds** then goes back normally and this happens multiple times.

I have managed to bypass this problem by using a connection to a VPN using OpenVPN client with the option `redirect-gateway` which is supposed to route all the traffic through the VPN network (This solution **worked when using TCP** for the VPN, on UDP I get the same problem...). I don't know if this is some kind of throttling or if it is a problem with the connection.

Do anyone have an idea on how to fix this problem? Why does it work correctly when using a VPN with TCP? Note that the problem also occurs on my phone and not just PC.

Other things I have tried:
Changing the MTU for the network interface on my PC.
Using another phone to connect to the WiFi network.

PS: This is my first post so excuse any missing information.

Comment: 115 Mbit/s in wifi settings

Comment: I am connecting to VPN using port 443 TCP (works also on other tcp ports!). Note that I do not own the OpenVPN server.